# including headers when writing a csv python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am in the habit of writing out a `CSV` in this particular way but I
am not aware how to include headers as most examples are not in this format.

```
ff = open('data.csv','w')

# Included here would be a typical for loop creating the below variables, i, list_name[i], list_date[i]

ff.write( "%7d, %s, %s\n" % (i, list_name[i], list_date[i]))
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow, you can use `code formatting` to actually highlight your code. You can indent your codelines with `4 spaces`  so that it renders properly and other users know where exactly is your code.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use the `csv` package, here is an example:

```
import csv

myData = [["first_name", "second_name", "Grade"],
      ['Alex', 'Brian', 'A'],
      ['Tom', 'Smith', 'B']]

myFile = open('file.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(myData)

print("done")
```